# Underscore/jQuery - combine hasClass and map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web page, I have a list of div and depending on the scroll position, one of them has a class 'active'.
I'd like to change the css of the class set to active.
Rather than looping through all the divs, I wanted to use the underscore library but I am not sure I am using it correctly with jQuery:

```
    _.map($('.item'), function(item){
      if (item.hasClass('active')) 
        // some code here
    });
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I assume my browser doesnt recognize 'item' as a jQuery object.

How can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: `.map()` functions are for creating a new Array of values that are derived from the values of the original. If you want to change the style of the element with the `active` class, why not just do `$(".item.active").css(...)`?

Comment: ...but the direct cause of the error is that `item` is a DOM elememt, not a jQuery object.

Comment: in this precise case, I could use $('.item.active') but more generally speaking, I am trying to find an elegant way to run through all the element of a certain class to fiddle with their css

Comment: `$(".item").each(function(i, item) { /* work with item */ })`

Comment: ok, I got it with each and using $(item) rather than item! thanks man! feel free to ad it as an answer so I can validate it. cheers